# Calculating sum of values in each child of dictionary for QTreeView

Tags: python, performance, beginner, hash-map, pyqt

There is data stored in JSON file with the following structure:

> goods_data = {"year" : {"month" : {"day" : {"01" : {"name" : "some item", "price" : "10.01", "category" : "root | first | sub first | twice sub first", "02" : {"name" : "another item", "price" : "10.99", "category" :  "root | first | sub first"} }}}}}

The task is to fill a `QTreeView` in which categories must have tree structure (the first column). The second column must contain the total sum of purchases  and percentage of the year for current category. The other columns are suppose to contain the total sum for each month for the current category.

The script I have written does what it is supposed to do but it takes too much time for the given data.

I understand that I include too many iterations inside each iteration, but I don't know the other way to do it. I think there is no reason to put all data that is being used, so I just have included the simplified dictionary.

How can I do it in more efficient and pythonic way?

[image: how it is supposed to look like]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -tt
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#from PySide.QtGui import *

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

import time
import types
import json
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
from datetime import datetime
import collections
import operator
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
goods_data = {"2015" : 
{
"09" : {
    "01" : {
        "1" : {
                "name" : "Red apples", "price" : "10.01", "category" : "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples"
              },
        "2" : {
                "name" : "Green  apples", "price" : "10.99", "category" :  "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples"
              }
            },
    "15" : {
        "1" : 
            {
            "name" : "Blue apples", "price" : "10.01", "category" : "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples"
            },
        "2" : {
        "name" : "Black  apples", "price" : "10.99", "category" :  "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples"
            }}
            },

 "10" : {
    "01" : {
        "1" : {
                "name" : "Oranges", "price" : "10", "category" : "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Oranges"
              },
        "2" : {
                "name" : "Oranges", "price" : "10", "category" :  "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Oranges"
              }
            },
    "15" : {
        "1" : 
            {
            "name" : "Oranges", "price" : "10", "category" : "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Oranges"
            },
        "2" : {
        "name" : "Apples", "price" : "10", "category" :  "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples"
            }}
            }               
            }
            }

#gj = 'goods.json'
#with open(gj) as f:
    #goods_data = json.load(f)

@pyqtSlot(float, float) 
def percentage(part,whole):
    if whole>0:
        return 100.00* float(part)/float(whole)
    else:
        return 0

@pyqtSlot(float, float) 
def perc_diff(prev,curr):
    return((float(curr)-prev)/abs(prev))*100.00


@pyqtSlot(dict, dict)   
def update(d, u):
    '''
    returns updated dictionary (initial dict, updating dict)
    '''
    for k, v in u.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, collections.Mapping):
            r = update(d.get(k, {}), v)     
            d[k] = r
        else:
            d[k] = u[k]

    return d


class MainFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        #super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent)
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.statusBar = QStatusBar()

        self.expences_cat_tree_stat = QTreeView()

        self.expences_cat_tree_stat.setAutoExpandDelay(0)
        self.expences_cat_tree_stat_model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.expences_cat_tree_stat.setModel( self.expences_cat_tree_stat_model )

        MainWindow = QVBoxLayout(self)
        MainWindow.addWidget(self.expences_cat_tree_stat)
        MainWindow.addWidget(self.statusBar)
        self.statusBar.showMessage("READY")

        self.setLayout(MainWindow)

        self.stat_cat_tree = self.load_stat_cat_tree(goods_data, self.expences_cat_tree_stat_model)

    @pyqtSlot(QObject, dict, QObject, dict, int,  QStandardItemModel)
    def TreeCatStat(self, children, parent, cat_dict, year, model):

        for child in sorted(children):
            child_item = QStandardItem(child)
            data_row = list([child_item])

            #   adding items without data to the row
            for i in range(model.columnCount()):
                data_row.append(QStandardItem())
            parent.appendRow(data_row)

            #   creating the path
            varforpath = child_item.parent()
            list_for_path = list([child_item.text()])

            while varforpath.parent() is not None:
                list_for_path.append(varforpath.text())
                varforpath = varforpath.parent()
            cat_path_str = str()    
            cat_path_str = ' > '.join(reversed(list_for_path))

            self.statusBar.showMessage(cat_path_str)

            #   iterating categories
            for sbct in sorted(cat_dict):
                cat_tot_year = float()
                #   if iterated category starts with path created from item
                if sbct.startswith(cat_path_str):
                    #   iterating months 
                    for i in range(2, model.columnCount()):
                        cat_tot_month = float()
                        #   inside each month iterating categories
                        for kpd in sorted(cat_dict):
                            # if iterated category inside the month starts with path from item
                            if kpd.startswith(cat_path_str): 
                                #   iterating month of categories that starts with path from item
                                for mm in sorted(cat_dict[kpd][year]):
                                    #   if name of the month from header matches name of the month from dictionary
                                    if model.headerData(i, Qt.Horizontal) == QDate.fromString(mm, "M").toString("MMMM"):
                                        #   iterating dates of month
                                        for dd in sorted(cat_dict[kpd][year][mm]):
                                            #   iterating numbers of purchases
                                            for ii in sorted(cat_dict[kpd][year][mm][dd]):
                                                #   iterating names of purchases
                                                for itn in sorted(cat_dict[kpd][year][mm][dd][ii]):
                                                    cat_tot_month += cat_dict[kpd][year][mm][dd][ii][itn]['sum']
                                                    cat_tot_year += cat_dict[kpd][year][mm][dd][ii][itn]['sum']
                                model.setData(model.indexFromItem(data_row[i]), cat_tot_month)
                    model.setData(model.indexFromItem(data_row[1]), cat_tot_year)

            whole = float(data_row[1].text())

            #   adding percentage to months             
            for val in range(2, model.columnCount()):
                part = model.indexFromItem(data_row[val]).data()
                str_out = str()
                if part is not None:
                    part = float(part)
                    if part > 0:
                        perc_str = format(percentage(part, whole), ".2f") 
                        str_out = str(format(part, ".2f")) + " (" + perc_str + "%)"
                    model.setData(model.indexFromItem(data_row[val]), str_out )



            if isinstance(children, types.DictType):
                self.TreeCatStat(children[child], child_item, cat_dict, year, model)


    @pyqtSlot(QObject, dict, QStandardItemModel)            
    def load_stat_cat_tree(self, data, model):
        start=time.clock()
        res = dict()
        ch_y = 2015
        tree = self.expences_cat_tree_stat
        exp_cat_tree_header = list(["Year / Category", "Total"])
        month_perc_item_list = list()
        overall_spent = float()
        prev_month_perc =float()
        one_month_sum_list  = list()
        cat_dict = dict()
        initial_dict_creation_time_start = time.clock()
        for yy in sorted(data):
            year_item = QStandardItem(yy)
            one_year_sum = float()
            for mm in sorted(data[yy]):
                date =  QDate.fromString(mm, "M")
                chosenMonth = date.toString("MMMM")
                month_item  = QStandardItem(chosenMonth)
                one_month_sum = float()
                for dd in sorted(data[yy][mm]):
                    one_day_sum = float()
                    day_str =  QDate.fromString(dd +" " + mm +" " + yy, "dd MM yyyy")
                    day_str_out = day_str.toString("d, dddd")
                    day_item = QStandardItem(day_str_out)
                    day_item.setToolTip(day_str.toString("d.MM.yy, dddd"))
                    for ii in sorted(data[yy][mm][dd]):
                        item_pr = float(data[yy][mm][dd][ii]["price"])
                        item_name=data[yy][mm][dd][ii]["name"]
                        #item_descr=data[yy][mm][dd][ii]["descr"]
                        item_cat = data[yy][mm][dd][ii]["category"].replace("|", ">")
                        path = item_cat
                        if path not in cat_dict:
                            cat_dict[path] = {yy: {mm: {dd: {ii: {item_name:  {"sum": item_pr} }}}}}
                        else:

                            if yy not in cat_dict[path]:
                                cat_dict[path][yy] = {}
                            if mm not in cat_dict[path][yy]:
                                cat_dict[path][yy][mm] = {}
                            if dd not in cat_dict[path][yy][mm]:
                                cat_dict[path][yy][mm][dd] = {}
                            if ii not in cat_dict[path][yy][mm][dd]:
                                cat_dict[path][yy][mm][dd][ii] = {}
                            if item_name not in cat_dict[path][yy][mm][dd][ii]:
                                cat_dict[path][yy][mm][dd][ii][item_name] = {"sum": item_pr}

                        if path:
                            d = t = {} # t is my temporary dictionary
                            for i in path.split(" > "):
                                t[i] = {}
                                t = t[i]
                                dct = update(res,d)
                        else:
                            dct = res
                        one_month_sum += float(item_pr)
                        one_year_sum += float(item_pr)

                if one_month_sum > 0:
                    exp_cat_tree_header.append(month_item.text())
                    one_month_sum_list.append( float(one_month_sum))

            initial_dict_creation_time_end = time.clock()
            initial_dict_creation_time_diff = str(initial_dict_creation_time_end - initial_dict_creation_time_start)
            print "initial dict creation time for " + yy + " -> " + initial_dict_creation_time_diff
            if one_year_sum > 0:
                year_row_list = [year_item, QStandardItem(str(format(one_year_sum, ".2f")))]

                for tm in one_month_sum_list:
                    year_row_list.append(QStandardItem(str(format(tm, ".2f")) + " (" +  format(percentage (tm, one_year_sum), ".2f") + "%)" ))
                    self.expences_cat_tree_stat_model.appendRow(year_row_list)

            model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(exp_cat_tree_header)
            self.TreeCatStat(res, year_item, cat_dict, yy, model)

        tree.expandAll()
        c = 0
        while c < len(exp_cat_tree_header):
            tree.resizeColumnToContents(c)
            c=c+1
        tree.collapseAll()
        item_to_expand = year_item
        tree.setExpanded(model.indexFromItem(item_to_expand), True)
        tree.scrollTo(model.indexFromItem(item_to_expand))
        end = time.clock()
        #print "%.2gs" % (end - start)
        print "calculations:", str(end - start)
        self.statusBar.showMessage("Calculations:" + str(end - start))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainFrame()
    main.show()
    main.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() -     main.rect().center())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you provide better `goods_data`? You’re missing to closing `}` plus your code fails with `KeyError: 'descr'` when they are added.

Comment: Thank you. Really I missed brackets. I've changed and extended the dictionary itself and removed 'descr' related error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For various reasonnings I’ll need slightly different `goods_data` than yours. As such, I used the following ones which includes 2 different years with duplicate months:

```
goods_data = {
    "2015" : {
        "09" : {
            "01" : {
                "01" : {"name" : "Red apples", "price" : "10.01", "category" : "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples", "descr":""}, 
                "02" : {"name" : "Green  apples", "price" : "10.99", "category" :  "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples", "descr":""},
            },
            "15" : {
                "01" : {"name" : "Blue apples", "price" : "10.01", "category" : "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples", "descr":""},
                "02" : {"name" : "Black  apples", "price" : "10.99", "category" :  "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples", "descr":""},
            },
        },
        "11" : {
            "01" : {
                "01" : {"name" : "Red apples", "price" : "10.01", "category" : "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples", "descr":""}, 
                "02" : {"name" : "Green  apples", "price" : "10.99", "category" :  "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Grappes", "descr":""},
            },
            "15" : {
                "01" : {"name" : "Blue apples", "price" : "10.01", "category" : "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples", "descr":""},
                "02" : {"name" : "Black  apples", "price" : "10.99", "category" :  "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Grappes", "descr":""},
            },
        },
    },
    "2016" : {
        "11" : {
            "01" : {
                "01" : {"name" : "Red apples", "price" : "10.01", "category" : "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples", "descr":""}, 
                "02" : {"name" : "Green  apples", "price" : "10.99", "category" :  "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Grappes", "descr":""},
            },
            "15" : {
                "01" : {"name" : "Blue apples", "price" : "10.01", "category" : "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples", "descr":""},
                "02" : {"name" : "Black  apples", "price" : "10.99", "category" :  "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Grappes", "descr":""},
            },
        },
        "12" : {
            "01" : {
                "01" : {"name" : "Red apples", "price" : "10.01", "category" : "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples", "descr":""}, 
                "02" : {"name" : "Green  apples", "price" : "10.99", "category" :  "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Grappes", "descr":""},
            },
            "15" : {
                "01" : {"name" : "Blue apples", "price" : "10.01", "category" : "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Apples", "descr":""},
                "02" : {"name" : "Black  apples", "price" : "10.99", "category" :  "Food and Grocery | Fruit and Vegetables | Fruit | Grappes", "descr":""},
            },
        },
    },
}
```

## You’ve got a bug

Ever wonder what happens when you use data that span on two years? Well things works strangely:

```
initial dict creation time for 2015 -> 0.000836
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e570b4030
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e570dcd20
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e570e1bb0
initial dict creation time for 2016 -> 0.006231
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e56d9fc30
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e570d7690
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e570dcd70
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e56d9fc30
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e570d7690
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e570dcd70
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e570d6280
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e56d9fc30
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e570d7690
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e570dcd70
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e570d6280
QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x557e56e5a070
calculations: 0.032324
```

On top of that, the `September` column appears twice in the `QTreeView` and data are displayed strangely within it.

This is probably due to `model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(exp_cat_tree_header)` being called within `for yy in sorted(data)`. Basically, you should first figure out the name of the columns, call `setHorizontalHeaderLabels` only once, and then process your data using your `for` loop.

You also add your `data_row` to both the tree-view and the `parent` element, which lead to weird results.

Due to other issues in your code, I won't develop further and we’ll see latter how to improve it.

## Imports

Importing modules with `from some_module import *` is frowned upon in Python. It pollutes the global namespace. Specify the list of things you want to import from a module instead, explicit is better than implicit.

I also have a tendancy to use the `from .. import` form when using modules for very specific features. I’d do `from time import clock` for instance, to make it more clear that the `time` module is for benchmarking purposes and not really related to your computations.

Also try to clean up unnecessary modules: you don't use `operator` or `datetime` for instance.

Lastly, `reload(sys);sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")` is discouraged and `sys.setdefaultencoding` is a no-op in Python 3. It can be used in very specific cases but doesn't apply to yours. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3828742/5069029) for more informations.

## pyqtSlot

First of, you don't even need to `from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot` since you already have `pyqtSlot` in the global namespace after `from PyQt5.QtCore import *`. One more reason to avoid `from .. import *`.

Second, slots in Qt are roughly callback functions for signals. You `connect` slots to specific signals and when one of these signals is `emit`ted, the corresponding slots runs. Since you don't use signals, you don't need slots.

Lastly, slots in pyQt are much less constrained than in C++. Most of the time you can `connect` a signal to a function without declaring it a slot first. Slots are mainly used to disambiguate overloading.

Just don't use `pyqtSlot`, you should figure out when to use it the day you’ll need it.

## Avoid unnecessary stuff

- `["Year / Category", "Total"]` is a list, no need to `list(["Year / Category", "Total"])`
- `format` already return a string, no need to `str(format(...))`
- methods of `MainFrame` can access attributes of `self`, no need to pass them as parameters
- you make no use of the descripton of an item, don't parse it (well, this one was removed in rev3 of the question)
- you could remove the need of importing `collections.Mapping` by using [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) approach:

  ```
  def update(d, u):
      for k,v in u.iteritems():
          r = d.get(k, {})
          try:
              update(r, v)
          except AttributeError: # v.iteritems() does not exist
              d[k] = v
          else:
              d[k] = r
  ```

  Also removed `return` at the end of the function. It is weird for this function that modifies `d` in place to return something.
- `replace`ing `'|'` by `'>'`  just to `split('>')` is useless, better `split('|')` directly.
- since you explicitly pass your input data to `load_stat_cat_tree`, you'd better of also passing it to the `__init__` of `MainFrame`. That way you can import the `json` module and read the input file only if you run your script from the command line.

## Naming

With a code this dense, using descriptive variable names for loop variables is necessary. `yy` might be convenient to type but very hard to follow when decyphering the code. On the other hand, you might want to shorten the names of you GUI componnents.

## Use better data structures to simplify the logic

8 nested `for` loops + some `if`s is really too much. It is both unreadable and probably sign of a bad design. Seeing, that you iterate over `sorted(cat_dict)` while iterating over `sorted(cat_dict)`, I gave up trying to deeply understand what your code does.

Instead of trying to parse your data and build your tree-view all at once, you should split your problem:

1. Parse your data and build a structure where each sub-category of each category of each year hold expenses for the relevant months;
2. Use this data structure to build a tree-view.

The main problem you might have faced is that you need a data structure that can handle an arbitrary number of sub-sub-…-sub-categories. In short, you need nested dictionnaries. But the burden of checking wether a sub-category already exists and create it if not and then expand it can make the code more verbose. Two solutions exists to simplify it:

1. the `setdefault` method of any dictionary. `d.setdefault(key, {})` will create `d[key] = {}` if it doesn't already exists and then return `d[key]`.
2. `collections.defaultdict` which are dictionaries who uses a callable to create missing elements on the fly:

   ```
   >>> d = defaultdict(int)
   >>> d['test']
   0
   >>> d
   defaultdict(<type: 'int'>, {'test': 0})
   ```

Where `defaultdict` can come in handy is that it allows to define recursive dictionnaries; allowing to access any nested level without troubles:

```
>>> def recursive_dict():
...     return defaultdict(recursive_dict)
...
>>> d = recursive_dict()
>>> d[1][2][3][4]
defaultdict(<function recursive_dict at 0x7f00d215a7d0>, {})
>>> d
defaultdict(<function recursive_dict at 0x7f00d215a7d0>, {1: defaultdict(<function recursive_dict at 0x7f00d215a7d0>, {2: defaultdict(<function recursive_dict at 0x7f00d215a7d0>, {3: defaultdict(<function recursive_dict at 0x7f00d215a7d0>, {4: defaultdict(<function recursive_dict at 0x7f00d215a7d0>, {})})})})})
```

But `defaultdict` are not magic, they are just regular dictionaries which implements the `__missing__` method. And in fact you could just build your own `recursive_dict` on top of `dict` pretty easily (not sure which one is faster, though):

```
>>> class recursive_dict(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...         self[key] = value = recursive_dict()
...         return value
...
>>> d = recursive_dict()
>>> d[1][2][3][4]
{}
>>> d
{1: {2: {3: {4: {}}}}}
```

Using this recursive dictionary, we can parse the data structure and, for each item (of each day, of each month, of each year), split its category into hierarchical parts and acces each level of the hierarchy easily. We can then, **at each level**, for the desired month, store its price:

- set it if it is the first price for this month; we can tell the first price appart since any month for any level will return a `recursive_dict` on first access. Once we set the value to a `float`, it will stay a `float`.
- add it if a total already exists.

We can do the same, at the same time, for the `'Total'` column. And end up with a dictionnary that, for each year and each category, yields the expenses of each sub-category for each month and the total for the year.

Pretty handy. We then just have to recursively iterate over this dictionary to add rows to our tree-view. And since totals and partials per months are available at each level of recursion, we can easily compute percentage while adding to the GUI.

Total: Only two pass over any data. One when building up totals and one when populating the GUI.

## Proposed improvements

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -tt
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from time import clock

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout,
                             QStatusBar, QTreeView)

import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

TOTAL = 'Total'


class recursive_dict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = value = recursive_dict()
        return value


def add_price(category, month, price):
    for column in (month, TOTAL):
        try:
            category[column] += price
        except TypeError:
            # First time we hit this month in this
            # category. Just store the first price.
            category[column] = price


class MainFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, goods_data):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.statusBar = QStatusBar()

        self.expences_cat_tree_stat = QTreeView()

        self.expences_cat_tree_stat.setAutoExpandDelay(0)
        self.expences_cat_tree_stat_model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.expences_cat_tree_stat.setModel(self.expences_cat_tree_stat_model)

        MainWindow = QVBoxLayout(self)
        MainWindow.addWidget(self.expences_cat_tree_stat)
        MainWindow.addWidget(self.statusBar)
        self.statusBar.showMessage("READY")

        self.setLayout(MainWindow)

        # Benchmark
        build_time = clock()

        self.expenses = recursive_dict()
        self._load_data(goods_data)

        months = sorted(set(col for year in self.expenses
                            for col, value in self.expenses[year].iteritems()
                            if isinstance(value, float) and col != TOTAL))
        # Debug: use every month of the year
        #months = ["{:02}".format(m) for m in xrange(1,13)]
        month_names = [QDate.fromString(month, "M").toString("MMMM")
                       for month in months]
        self.expences_cat_tree_stat_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
                ['Year / Category', TOTAL] + month_names)

        for year in sorted(self.expenses):
            item = QStandardItem(year)
            row = self._build_category_row(self.expenses[year], item, months)
            self.expences_cat_tree_stat_model.appendRow(row)

        self.expences_cat_tree_stat.collapseAll()
        # Recursively expand first category of last year
        expanded_item = item
        while expanded_item is not None:
            expanded_index = self.expences_cat_tree_stat_model.indexFromItem(
                    expanded_item)
            self.expences_cat_tree_stat.setExpanded(expanded_index, True)
            expanded_item = expanded_item.child(0)
        self.expences_cat_tree_stat.scrollTo(
                self.expences_cat_tree_stat_model.indexFromItem(item))

        for i in xrange(len(month_names)+2):
            self.expences_cat_tree_stat.resizeColumnToContents(i)

        # Show benchmark
        build_time = clock() - build_time
        message = "Building time: {:.6f}s".format(build_time)
        print message
        self.statusBar.showMessage(message)


    def _load_data(self, goods_data):
        for year in goods_data:
            build_time = clock()
            year_expenses = self.expenses[year]
            for month in goods_data[year]:
                for items in goods_data[year][month].itervalues():
                    for good in items.itervalues():
                        price = float(good['price'])
                        current_category = year_expenses
                        add_price(current_category, month, price)
                        for category in good['category'].split('|'):
                            category = category.strip()
                            current_category = current_category[category]
                            add_price(current_category, month, price)
            build_time = clock() - build_time
            message = "Initial dict creation time for {}: {:.6f}s".format(
                    year, build_time)
            print message
            self.statusBar.showMessage(message)


    def _build_category_row(self, goods_values, parent, months):
        total = goods_values[TOTAL]
        data_row = [parent, QStandardItem("{:.2f}".format(total))]

        for month in months:
            if month in goods_values:
                partial = goods_values[month]
                percent = 100 * partial / total
                label = "{:.2f} ({:.2f}%)".format(partial, percent)
                data_row.append(QStandardItem(label))
            else:
                data_row.append(QStandardItem())

        for category in sorted(goods_values):
            if category != TOTAL and category not in months:
                row = self._build_category_row(
                        goods_values[category],
                        QStandardItem(category),
                        months)
                parent.appendRow(row)

        return data_row


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    import json

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    with open('goods.json') as f:
        goods_data = json.load(f)
    main = MainFrame(goods_data)

    main.show()
    main.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() - main.rect().center())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Which outputs:

```
Initial dict creation time for 2015: 0.000545s
Initial dict creation time for 2016: 0.000115s
Building time: 0.022126s
```

Comment: I do appreciate your reply and such an extended explanation. Thank you! The performance increase is just astonishing. It was two seconds, as one can see on screenshot I attached, and now with your code it takes just 0.037. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SergiiArtele Agreed that a ×50 time improvement can be great. And from my own timings, the code spends most of its time in Qt internals building the tree-view. Anyway, I added an other way to create recursive dictionaries. I’m not sure if it is more comprehensive or faster, but the output is prettier with it.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently trying to understand and apply what you wrote. It looks like I have to recode all my program, because that piece of code it's just a part of three thousand lines program, and in it I need recursion very often for various purposes. thanks a lot